# Complete the following verbal analogy!

Tags: logical-deduction, word

MAKE :  DALE ::  (?)  : PALE

Hint: pattern recognition or semantical relation

(?)=solution containing 4 letters

: means  'to'  , :: means 'as'

Answer (score 1):

My answer is

> YAKE

Because:

> All other letters of the two sides being the same, we really have just "M:D::?:P" or, using a a1z26 cipher, "13:4::?:16." The most straightforward method is to subtract 9, giving ?=25 or Y. Although uncommon, "YAKE" is a valid word, and my solution to the puzzle.

Comment: That word is apparently defined as “a person who creates horrible ideas in a time of need”. Could fit.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is one of four words

> Fake, lake, sake, or wake

If you look at

> How "make" and "dale" are spoken, they consist of one hard and one soft sound, with "make" being soft-hard and "dale" being hard-soft. Since "pale" follows the same sound rule as "dale" and shares the same last 3 letters, it makes since that the (?) would follow "make"'s sound rule and share its last 3 letters. Of all the available options (bake, cake, fake, lake, rake, sake, take, wake), only "fake", "lake", "sake", and "wake" follow the sound rule.

I imagine that there's something I'm missing that will narrow it down to one of these words.